# What form of message is good for sending values ​to Kafka?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I currently have a development environment as follows.

- spring-boot 2.X
- spring-kafka 2.5.5
- Kafka version 2.5.1
- Producer/Consumer Key Serializer/Deserializer = String(De)serializer.class
- Producer/Consumer value Serializer/Deserializer = Json(De)serializer.class

When sending a Kafka message by Producer, the custom DTO(or POJO) is converted to `JSON String` type through `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(customDto)`.

- ProducerFactory<String, String>
- KafkaTemplate<String, String>

```
ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, msg); // The message is a JSON String variable made with ObjectMapper.

ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(record);
```

And when a `JSON String` message is received in Consumer, it is converted into the corresponding DTO(or POJO) through `ObjectMapper.readValue(message, CustomDto.class)` and received.

- ConsumerFactory<String, String>

> For reference, there is not only one type of Custom DTO.

I am wondering if it is correct to send and receive Custom DTO by converting it to `JSON String` each time as above.

Or is there a way to send and receive Custom DTO directly without conversion? I would like to use a generic type. How about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a better way to send a complex type through Kafka and it includes a structure that can be serialized and desterilized automatically.

1. Use Avro Schema https://avro.apache.org/
2. Add the confluent schema registry to handle the serialization/deserialization process  and validation. [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-platform/data-compatibility/?utm_medium=sem&utm_source=google&utm_campaign=ch.sem_br.brand_tp.prs_tgt.confluent-brand_mt.xct_rgn.emea_lng.eng_dv.all&utm_term=confluent%20schema%20registry&creative=&device=c&placement=&gclid=CjwKCAjw07qDBhBxEiwA6pPbHuefUPo6KERtrMBEvt1N_aGJUJhLaoUL0zM3eGN3cp3JZSyvmH4L6BoCtLIQAvD_BwE)

check out this [example](https://github.com/simplesteph/kafka-avro-course) to see how clean and efficient it is.

Comment: Thanks! In addition to the answers below, I'll find out and decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be converted to a `byte[]`, but you can use the (De)Serializers provided by the framework instead of doing it yourself.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looking at your answer, it seems like i can customize an existing (de)serializer. Let's review the official docs and its use.